# Need Help adding checkboxes to listview in powershell

Tags: wpf, listview, powershell

I am currently working on making a GUI that will retrieve SQL databases and back them up. My ListView will populate the databases but I would like to show checkboxes next to each database. This will allow the user to only backup desired databases.

In Visual Studio, I added 4 checkboxes (just to play around and understand how to make them work) to my listview. I am not exactly sure how i can have powershell show checkboxes next to the tabulated data because by default i see nothing.

This is what my WPF code looks like

```
<Window x:Class="SQLGUI.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SQLGUI"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="547.722" Width="861.104" Background="#FF4F4A4A">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox x:Name="instance" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,76,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <Button x:Name="selectdatabase" Content="Load Database" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="135,76,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92"/>
        <ListView x:Name="listView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="350" Margin="10,103,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="812">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Database Name" DisplayMemberBinding ="{Binding 'Database Name'}" Width="200"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Created" DisplayMemberBinding ="{Binding 'Created'}" Width="200"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Last Backup" DisplayMemberBinding ="{Binding 'Last Backup'}" Width="200"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Size(KB)" DisplayMemberBinding ="{Binding 'Size(KB)'}" Width="200"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
            <CheckBox x:Name="box1" Content="Test"/>
            <CheckBox x:Name="box2" Content="Test 2"/>
            <CheckBox x:Name="box3" Content="Test 3"/>
            <CheckBox x:Name="box4" Content="Test 4"/>
        </ListView>
        <Button x:Name="backup" Content="Backup" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="130,482,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and this is how i am tabulating data on the WPF

```
$WPFselectdatabase.add_click({
$WPFlistView.items.clear()
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Sqlserver.smo")
$sqlserver=New-Object ("Microsoft.Sqlserver.management.smo.server") "MS-SQL"
foreach($sqldatabase in $sqlserver.databases){
$sqldatabase.name | select-object @{Name='Database Name';EX={$sqldatabase.name}}, @{Name='Created';Ex={$sqldatabase.CreateDate}},@{Name='Last Backup';Ex={$sqldatabase.LastBackupDate}},@{Name='Size(KB)'; EX={($sqldatabase.Size)}} | % {$WPFlistView.AddChild($_)}}
})
```

Comment: what is this i dont even... you're coding ... wpf UI... powershell?  huh?  I feel faint.  I need to lie down.  Can you explain what powershell is doing in your question?  It may help with the dizziness...

Comment: Wow.  One real question--are you using WPF in powershell because you are developing powershell applications and using WPF for complex input, or are you coding a WPF application and think that it's normal to code them via powershell?

Comment: @will I am trying to automate the backup of SQL databses, the reason I am utilizing powershell is because in the past, using precompiled .NET or C# applications have caused trouble and there was no way to fix issues on the go. My reason for using powershell is simple in the sense that it can be fixed and modified on the go and I am using WPF to ensure maximum simplicity for the end user.--albeit at the cost of major complications for me :P

Comment: "I am trying to automate the backup of SQL databases" - why? SQL has built-in tools for creating and managing backups.

Comment: I can see that.  @Bill_Stewart might be onto something, tho.  Good luck!

Comment: @Bill_Stewart the backups are unscheduled, and will usually require a backup followed by a restore due to a system upgrade/fresh install, furthermore, the powershell script will be used across multiple systems. it will serve as a centralized way for the user (who may not be familiar with SQL databases) to manage multiple instances of SQL running on 1 system.

Answer (score 0):

After searching through stack overflow,  I was able to to find the solution!

It seems that a new GridView Column needs to be added with a DataTemplate. Adding the following piece of code solved the problem.

```
<GridViewColumn>
   <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
       <CheckBox />
    </DataTemplate>
   </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

so the final GUI code ends up looking as such

```
<Window x:Class="SQLGUI.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SQLGUI"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="547.722" Width="861.104" Background="#FF4F4A4A">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox x:Name="instance" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,76,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <Button x:Name="selectdatabase" Content="Load Database" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="135,76,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92"/>
        <ListView x:Name="listView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="350" Margin="10,103,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="834">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Database Name" DisplayMemberBinding ="{Binding 'Database Name'}" Width="300"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Created" DisplayMemberBinding ="{Binding 'Created'}" Width="200"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Last Backup" DisplayMemberBinding ="{Binding 'Last Backup'}" Width="200"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Size" DisplayMemberBinding ="{Binding 'Size(MB)'}" Width="150"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <Button x:Name="backup" Content="Backup" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="130,482,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score -1):

[ListView.CheckBoxes Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.checkboxes(v=vs.110).aspx)

I think you need to add the CheckBoxes attribute to the ListView element:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" CheckBoxes="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="350" Margin="10,103,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="812">
```

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work.  Adding that parameter causes the GUI to not load.